# How to get a smooth progression of the progressBar during establishing a connection to the server?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

Most examples of how to use `publishProgress` call it in very few discrete steps (e.g. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/UsingAsyncTasktodownloadabigfile.htm) typically one call before and one after `httpClient.execute`.

In my application I noticed that most of the time (say 3 seconds) is spent while establishing the connection to the server.

So during that time my progress bar looks like stalled to the user. To give him visual feedback that there is still something going on in the background, I would like to kind of animate the progress bar during that waiting time. E.g. starting at 0% and adding 2% to the progression every half a second, while waiting for coming back from `httpClient.execute` (e.g. up to 60%).

I would appreciate any suggestions very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Handler` to update the `ProgressBar` while `execute()` runs. For example in the `onPreExecute()` of the `AsyncTask` start a `Runnable` like below:

```
private static final int UPDATE_STEP = 500; // My convention is to update the progress with 1 for every 500ms
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
          progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 1); 
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_STEP);
     }

}

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, UPDATE_STEP); 
}
```

In the `doInBackground()` method, after the `execute()` call finishes:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);// cancel the manual ProgressBar updates
int remainderProgress = 100 - progressBar.getProgress(); // I assumed that 100 is the max progress
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Your code would run out of the box, if you edit the following: removeCallbacks needs the runnable as an argument: `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);`

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger Yes, `removeCallbacks()` expects a `Runnable`, it was a confusion from my part. I've edited the answer to correct this.